# get repository in command symfony6

Tags: php, symfony

I want to use repository to fetch the data from DB.

However in command how can I get the repository?

For example I put the `SiteDataRepository`  in execute,

```
protected function execute(SiteDataRepository $siteDataRepository,InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
{
```

however there comes error

```
Fatal error: Declaration of App\Command\OpArticleCommand::execute(App\Repository\SiteDataRepository $siteDataRepository,
```

Or is there any method to do the `SQL sentence` in execute()?

Comment: Please share more details, like the exact error message and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can autowire your repository but not directly in your execute method.

Add a constructor (if there is none already) to inject your repository service.

If your command extends `Command` it should be something like:

```
class YourCommand extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'command-name';
    protected static $defaultDescription = 'description';
    private SiteDataRepository $siteDataRepository;

    public function __construct(SiteDataRepository $siteDataRepository)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->siteDataRepository = $siteDataRepository;
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName(self::$defaultName)
            ->setDescription(self::$defaultDescription)
        ;
    }
}
```

Note that we are using the configure method because we do not call the parent constructor with a name, we could remove the configure method and do it in the constructor instead.

Comment: Thank you very much!!. I am newbee for symfony6 but it becomes more  flexible than 3 or 4. cool.